# History push stacking with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history

I'm trying to do some simple routing with react-router and I encountered a problem I never had...
I'm trying to do routing with a layout that persists with route switching, so I have something like this:

```
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Redirect to="/vouchers/fixes" />} />
            <Route exact path="/vouchers/fixes" component={Vouchers} />
            <Route exact path="/vouchers/reportes" component={Vouchers} />
            <Route exact path="/recibos/fixes" component={NotFound} />
            <Route exact path="/recibos/reportes" component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

And in the layout i have this redirection

```
        <List>
          <ListItem button onClick={() => history.push("vouchers/fixes")}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <InboxIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Vouchers" />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button onClick={() => history.push("recibos/fixes")}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <MailIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Recibos" />
          </ListItem>
```

So when I try to navigate between routes instead of replacing the URL with only the new route, they get concatenated I end up with this

```
http://localhost:3000/vouchers/recibos/vouchers/recibos/vouchers/recibos/vouchers/recibos/vouchers/vouchers/vouchers/vouchers/recibos/recibos/fixes
```

One gets added in every click... I tried getting rid of the / and simplify the routes by calling them vouchers and receipts and it works normally...

Comment: not sure, but try history.push("/vouchers/fixes")

Comment: Or also use the `Link` or `NavLink` components. They are semantically more correct to use than a button anyway.

Comment: all <Route> contain 'exact' keyword. It seems a conflict with other routes. You can remove the 'exact' keyword from others and can try. Let know if it works :)